# How to ascertain if a mercurial patch is already applied

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

I am using mercurial queues to apply patches. I have the .patch files and series file. I copy those into .hg/patches directory. Then I run the following:

> hg qpush -all

Now, say patch A fails. I investigate and find that patch A was already applied. So I remove patch A from the series file and do the process again.

My question is: How can I safely know that the reason my patch has failed to apply is because it is already applied? Or Is there a way to know beforehand that the patch is already applied?